# How can I copy a file (.txt format) from my computer to docker container

Tags: powershell, docker, hdfs

I am trying to copy a .txt file from my computer into a docker container using the command below which I run in powershell:

```
docker cp SelectedWords.txt  27eab29f7d03:/selectwords/
```

The command is run, but when I check docker, the file does not appear.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: `docker cp SelectedWords.txt 27eab29f7d03:/selectwords/SelectedWords.txt` make sure that you have the folder `selectwords` first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the trailing slash

```
docker cp SelectedWords.txt 27eab29f7d03:/selectwords
```

Your file should be at /selectwords/SelectedWords.txt

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. All is well now

Comment: @IoudomFoubiJephte Great. Please mark the answer as accepted if you've found it useful.